# Basename not working connected-react-router

Tags: javascript, connected-react-router

I'm using connected-react-router with my react redux app.
I need server side rendering and client side rendering (I'm using a react component in a symfony twig template via limenius react bundle).

My probleme is that i cannot use basename properly. I have a locale isocode in my URL (www.localhost.com/fr/mypage)

If i declare a basename '/fr/' in history:

```
<Route exact path={`/${isocode}/checkout/customize`} component={Customize} />
```

works !

... but I want this :

```
<Route exact path="checkout/customize" component={Customize} />
```

and it does not work !

What i have in my app.js:

```js
export const App = () => {
  const store = ReactOnRails.getStore('CustomizeStore');
  const state = store.getState();
  const { isocode } = state.general.data.locale;
  const history = createHistory({
    basename: `/${isocode}/`,
    initialEntries: [state.router.location.pathname],
  });

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path={`/${isocode}/checkout/customize`} component={Customize} />
        </Switch>
      </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

and in my store.js

```js
export const createHistory = historyConfig =>
  isServer ? createMemoryHistory(historyConfig) : createBrowserHistory();

export default (props, context) => {
  const { baseURL } = props.general.data.api;
  const { isocode } = props.general.data.locale;
  const history = createHistory({ basename: `/${isocode}/`, initialEntries: [context.pathname] });

  return createStore(
    reducers(history),
    { ...props },
    composeEnhancers(
      applyMiddleware(thunk, routerMiddleware(history)),
    ),
  );
};
```

---

What i expect in my app.js:

```js
<Provider store={store}>
  <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="checkout/customize" component={Customize} />
    </Switch>
  </ConnectedRouter>
</Provider>
```

I've read that the basename for "browserRouter" and "staticRouter" provided by react-router should be declared in history props of ConnectRouter component.

What I'm doing wrong ? Is connect-react-router a good choice for my redux ssr application or should i use react-router ? (I'm using immutable.js and i want to implement hot-reloading if possible =)

A big thanks !

Comment: UP PLZ connect-react-router

Comment: Hey, did you solve this? if yes could you please post it?

Comment: No sorry, i didnt

Comment: did you find any solution ? I am stuck at same point.

Comment: nope, there is no solution yet. Problem can be solved by forking and changing source librairies because they won't patch it till it's not their problem...

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem a few days ago and I solved it by setting the `basename` in the `createBrowserHistory`, like this:

```js
const history = createBrowserHistory({ basename: “/baseName” })
```

Comment: Hey @Tralgar, I found a much better way of achieving this without using the `BrowserRouter`